# jQuery resize losing border

Tags: jquery, css, resize, border

**Hi everyone!**

I'm having a few issues with the [jQuery UI Resize](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/) loosing the border on the textarea I'm resizing (see images). Can you help?

*Borders showing as intended:*
[image: borders showing as intended]

*Right border hidden:*
[image: border missing]

*Firebug screenshot: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyR43.png)*
[image: Firebug screenshot]

Comment: Please try to give us some of the CSS you are using. Screenshots doesn't really help for this.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of Firebug - hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed in the patch -> https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/pull/713/

Answer (score 1):

The textarea must be in a container that has `overflow` set to `hidden`. Use Firebug to inspect the style of the parent elements. That's all that can be said without seeing the CSS.

Comment: The textarea already has a container with overflow set to hidden. I've added a screenshot of firebug.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was unclear. The `overflow` property is causing your problem. The overflowing parts of the textarea are being hidden.